# Intu Manager gives: Error getting robot versions

Tags: project-intu

I am running de Intu Manager (Intu-Tooling-Win64) on my windows laptop.
The SSO proces works fine, but after I return I get the following message:

[image]

I have an organisation (e-office) and the default group in the rg-gateway and I see one device:

[image]

So what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had downloaded the files when I was at another location, it turned out that the website : http://75.126.4.106/xray/ was being blocked by firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the network operation blocked or the version url can't be reached at the time on your try. It is checking the version number from cloud. 
@mpjjonker - that is very sad to blocking the IP by firewall. It looks like rest call returns null response.