# Intu Avatar won't connect: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: project-intu, intu

I am trying to setup a INTU connections using the avatar.

I have the avatar running:

[image]

I have copied the credential information in the m_variables section in the  config.json

The Intu Manager keeps trying to connect to parent
[image]

Below is the log from the avatar:

```
<RI> Initialized touch support.

UnloadTime: 2.382588 ms
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting SelfDisplayGesture(Clone) (DocumentModel) -> DocumentManager.Document Input (DocumentModel)
Platform assembly: D:\Software\IoT\GoPiGo\Self-Avatar-Win64\intu_avatar_Data\Managed\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting TextToSpeechWidget(Clone) (DisableMicData) -> MicWidget(Clone).Disable (DisableMicData)
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting AvatarWidget (DisableMicData) -> MicWidget(Clone).Disable (DisableMicData)
[WARNING][AvatarWidget]: Mood not defined for NONE.
[WARNING][AvatarWidget]: Mood not defined for NONE.
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting MicWidget(Clone) (AudioData) -> SelfMicrophoneSensor(Clone).Audio (AudioData)
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting SelfSpeechGesture(Clone) (TextToSpeechData) -> TextToSpeechWidget(Clone).Text (TextToSpeechData)
[STATUS][GestureManager]: Gesture update_status/e83cb44b-644d-4b82-a5f7-86b6886bc3c6 added.
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting TextToSpeechWidget(Clone) (SpeakingStateData) -> SelfSpeechGesture(Clone).Speaking Input (SpeakingStateData)
[STATUS][GestureManager]: Gesture tts/dee17c80-8474-4343-b961-602c0f169459 added.
[STATUS][GestureManager]: Gesture display/9c3e0b2c-48c3-45d9-a546-3794b9632d45 added.
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting SelfStatusGesture(Clone) (StatusData) -> AvatarWidget.Status (StatusData)
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting TextToSpeechWidget(Clone) (LevelData) -> AvatarWidget.Level (LevelData)
[STATUS][Widget]: Auto-Connecting MicWidget(Clone) (LevelData) -> AvatarWidget.Level (LevelData)
[STATUS][AvatarWidget]: Starting avatar.
[WARNING][AvatarWidget]: Mood not defined for NONE.
Setting up 2 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 2660 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 256c -> priority: 1 
12/16/2016 2:07:03 PM|Fatal|WebSocket.connect|System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

                              at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                              at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                              at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
                              at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[STATUS][TopicClient]: OnSocketClosed: An exception has occurred while connecting.No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean requireSocketPolicy) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remote_end_point) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[STATUS][TopicClient]: Reconnecting in 5 seconds.
[STATUS][SensorManager]: Sensor aae9e913-13b6-4cb0-aad7-a57d594224ff added.
[STATUS][TopicClient]: Reconnecting in 5 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your computer sit behind a proxy?

Comment: We had some firewall issues, see also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163999/intu-manager-gives-error-getting-robot-versions but those are gone now...

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried updating your m_variables in the config file recently, in my investigations it seems this is a token which will expire.

Comment: Thanks for your response, for this project we have chosen for a different approach. I don't know how I can flag my question with this status ? So I cannot tell you anytime soon if this tip helps...